# PluginApplicationException: Failed to apply plugin class 'FlutterPlugin'

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I got strange bugs,

After I upgrade Android Studio :

[image]

I created an Android project, run it a success.

Then I tried to import `Flutter Module` to this Android project.

I had these exceptions,

> Blockquote
>
> Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.PluginApplicationException: Failed to apply plugin class 'FlutterPlugin'.

> Caused by: org.Gradle.API.InvalidUserCodeException: Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'maven' was added by plugin class 'FlutterPlugin'

I searched but did not find the solution for that exception, even `Clean project`, `Gradle clean build`, and `Restart & Invalidate Project`.

Please help me to solve this,

Thanks,

p/s: At the previous Android Studio version, I did that normally. (very simple)

**Run android project success before import flutter module**

[image]

**Project structure**

[image: Project structure]

**`settings.Gradle` after imported Flutter Module**

[image]

**Current Version**

[image]

**`Gradle clean build` command line**

[image]

Comment: Now, I did not get this issue anymore.

Answer (score 22):

For Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 2 and Flutter 2.2.3 have the same issues,follow these steps fix it.

1.open android project settings.gradle,change **FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS** to **PREFER_PROJECT**

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.PREFER_PROJECT)
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
}
```

}

2. open android project build.gradle add these configs

   allprojects {
   repositories {
   google()
   jcenter()
   }
   }
3. rebuild the project

https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/initialization/resolve/RepositoriesMode.html

Comment: UPD: Faced the issue in February 2022. The solution fixed it, but as it was stated in a warning, jcenter() got shut down, so it is removed from settings.gradle, and also should not be listed in allprojects {...} (step 2)

Comment: Instead of changing project settings remove the entire `dependencyResolutionMangament`, it'll solve the error.

Answer (score 0):

For Flutter 2.2.3, downgrade gradle version. don't use gradle 7. it's not compatible with flutter.gradle.

in android project build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2'
 ...
}
```

in android project gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-bin.zip
```

Comment: I created a new android app, after that, created a new flutter module using android studio. The problem reported appeared. After using your solution, I got a new error: 
Could not find method dependencyResolutionManagement() for arguments [settings_dc3nelhdckh73npb3p919kj3r$_run_closure1@58223593] on settings 'MyApplication' of type org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettings

I'm going to post later when I fix it.