# Flutter module into android native

Tags: android, flutter

I'm trying to add a flutter module in a native android, but I'm getting this error:
Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'maven' was added by plugin class 'FlutterPlugin'

I tried following these steps from the documentation
https://docs.flutter.dev/development/add-to-app/android/project-setup#option-b---depend-on-the-modules-source-code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem.

```
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> Failed to apply plugin class 'FlutterPlugin'.
> Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'maven' was added by plugin class 'FlutterPlugin'
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating script.
at build_ad08z2wkzvgyoe9c30qc5q6cf.run(D:\AndroidProject\flutter_module\.android\Flutter\build.gradle:27)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.PluginApplicationException: Failed to apply plugin class 'FlutterPlugin'.
at flutter_eru21m51zf44m5fepcqc90y7v.run(C:\D\Flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle:81)
```

I know the reason but I don't know how to fix it.

I think this problem arises because the version of gradle is over 7.0.
The 7.0 Gradle need centralizing repositories declaration, see picture2
[Gradle Documentation Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SG8Qg.png)
However,"flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle:81" config thie allProject{} and add maven,
so report errors.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/69101071/21557657 it solve my problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).